# add numbers to right of decimal in react javascript, append string, toFixed method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decimal

This function is meant to represent numbers input by a user as you would for a standard calculator:

```
addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
    let equation = this.state.equation
    console.log(parseFloat(equation))

    if(newLogic==="10%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.10)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }else if (newLogic==="15%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.15)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }else if (newLogic==="20%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.20)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }
    else{
      // we're adding more numbers
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + newLogic;
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }

  }
}
```

^It also contains some logic for performing a simple multiplication- which is important to the program- anyway...

The problem with that code is- when a user inputs a new value- it was always appear to the left of the decimal place- however- for reasons of exactitude- we need it to begin at the rightmost digital, i.e. in this string, we would want to begin where you see the `7`:

```
0.07
```

At the moment the `7` always appears here:

```
7.00
```

As more numbers get added they increment like so:

```
77.00
```

Whereas we want them to increment like to:

```
00.77
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using the input with type = 'decimal'?

Comment: cant you just ```input / 100``` that will make your decimal in tenths without changing anything